# Trouble creating a SQL Server function to test formats

Tags: sql-server, email-validation

The original code is from this website, but somehow, the page got lost so I cannot reference it. But here is the original code:

```
DECLARE @email_address VARCHAR(2000) = 'aname@acompany.com'

IF (
     CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address))) = 0 
    AND  LEFT(LTRIM(@email_address),1) <> '@' 
    AND  RIGHT(RTRIM(@email_address),1) <> '.' 
    AND  CHARINDEX('.',@email_address ,CHARINDEX('@',@email_address)) - CHARINDEX('@',@email_address ) > 1 
    AND  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address ))) - LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address)),'@','')) = 1 
    AND  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address)))) >= 3 
    AND  (CHARINDEX('.@',@email_address ) = 0 AND CHARINDEX('..',@email_address ) = 0)
    )
   print 'valid email address'
ELSE
   print 'not valid'
```

From that, I was going to write a function I could call on to test formats. Figuring I would like to use this later to test for Twitter, and other social IDs, I figured I would make it a code that accepted the sting as well as the format to test.

Here is what I wrote:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestForType](@strString VARCHAR(2000), @strFormat VARCHAR(2000))

RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
--DECLARE @strString VARCHAR(2000)= 'aname@acompany.com'
DECLARE @email_address VARCHAR(2000)
--DECLARE @strFormat VARCHAR(2000) = 'email'
DECLARE @bitTrueFalse bit
SET @email_address =@strString
--SET @bitTrueFalse = If(@strFormat = 'email') BEGIN
If(@strFormat = 'email') BEGIN
    IF (@email_address <> 'none@pletter.com'
        AND CHARINDEX(' ',LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address))) = 0 
        AND  LEFT(LTRIM(@email_address),1) <> '@' 
        AND  RIGHT(RTRIM(@email_address),1) <> '.' 
        AND  CHARINDEX('.',@email_address ,CHARINDEX('@',@email_address)) - CHARINDEX('@',@email_address ) > 1 
        AND  LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address ))) - LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address)),'@','')) = 1 
        AND  CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address)))) >= 3 
        AND  (CHARINDEX('.@',@email_address ) = 0 AND CHARINDEX('..',@email_address ) = 0)
        )

            SET @bitTrueFalse =  1

    ELSE 
        SET @bitTrueFalse =  0
    END --END IF
ELSE
    SET @bitTrueFalse =  NULL
END --End IF
RETURN @bitTrueFalse
```

I got this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TestForType, Line 41
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'.

I don't understand. I want it to return the value of `@bitTrueFalse`.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions for a title.  Please include the the language (preferably as a tag) as well.

Comment: You're lacking another `END` after the `RETURN` (to close the `BEGIN` at the very beginning)

Comment: A year plus late on showing my gratitude, but I thank you. I cannot give attaboy points, yet, else I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your innermost `IF` doesn't have a `BEGIN`, so basically your `END` are unbalanced.

The `END` just before the `RETURN` is the one that belongs to the very first `BEGIN` (just after the `AS`) and therefore, your `RETURN` comes **after** the end of the function code. Put your `RETURN` *before* that very last `END` and you should be fine

Your code **really** looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestForType]
    (@strString VARCHAR(2000), @strFormat VARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN -- (1)
    DECLARE @email_address VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @bitTrueFalse bit

    SET @email_address = @strString

    IF (@strFormat = 'email') BEGIN   -- (2)
       IF (@email_address <> 'none@pletter.com'
          AND CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(@email_address))) = 0 
          .... all those other conditions ......

          SET @bitTrueFalse =  1   -- no BEGIN here....
       ELSE 
          SET @bitTrueFalse =  0
    END -- END IF (2)
    ELSE
        SET @bitTrueFalse =  NULL
END --- (1)

-- this ends up being *AFTER* the last END 
RETURN @bitTrueFalse
```